# HTML - checkbox is displayed black with initial-scale=1.0

Tags: css, html

On a mobile device (e.g. Samsung Galaxy) a Checkbox appears to have a dark background, if I change the initial-scale to a value of 1.1 it has got a white background again. What is going on. Is a scale of 1.1 a good solution?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.1">
```

Answer (score 0):

change to this one

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

Comment: it does not fix the checkbox appearance